How are base-R graphic functions recognizing the color arguments in the string format?
When a color argument is passed into the R function similarly to plot((x=seq(1,10,by=.1)),sin(x),type="l",col="orange"), where is the plot function receiving the exact values for the orange color from? There are at least 657 color constants (length(colors())
), so, hardcoding every color into a graphic function seems to be improbable. Is there an object in R where the color names and their respective values (hex, rgb?) are saved?
I have tried this (not helping much)
> col2rgb
function (col, alpha = FALSE) 
{
    if (any(as.character(col) %in% "0")) 
        stop("numerical color values must be positive", domain = NA)
    if (is.factor(col)) 
        col <- as.character(col)
    .Call(C_col2rgb, col, alpha)
}
<bytecode: 0x0000019b30ea92b8>
<environment: namespace:grDevices>
>

Expected is something like this but without the unnecessary col2rgb:
> Map(col2rgb,colors()[1:10])
$white
      [,1]
red    255
green  255
blue   255

$aliceblue
      [,1]
red    240
green  248
blue   255

$antiquewhite
      [,1]
red    250
green  235
blue   215

$antiquewhite1
      [,1]
red    255
green  239
blue   219

$antiquewhite2
      [,1]
red    238
green  223
blue   204

$antiquewhite3
      [,1]
red    205
green  192
blue   176

$antiquewhite4
      [,1]
red    139
green  131
blue   120

$aquamarine
      [,1]
red    127
green  255
blue   212

$aquamarine1
      [,1]
red    127
green  255
blue   212

$aquamarine2
      [,1]
red    118
green  238
blue   198

